# Android notification - setSound does not work

Tags: android, audio, notifications

I have looked at several question regarding this topic and all seem to suggest that simply using `.setSound(alarmSound)` in the notification builder will cause the phone to play a sound with the notification. However, I'm doing just that and it doesn't work.

I'm probably missing something but I can't find what it is.

Here is the code I'm using to issue the notification:

```
private void newArrivalNotification(String locId, String userId) {

    ...

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent mainActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, locId.hashCode(),
            mainActivity, 0);

    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    if(alarmSound == null) {
        Log.w("GcmIntentService", "alarmSound is null");
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(msg))
                .setSound(alarmSound, AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION)
                .setTicker(msg)
                .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    Notification arrivalNotification = mBuilder.build();
    arrivalNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, arrivalNotification);
}
```

Can you spot anything I did wrong? I looked for hours and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are modifying the default notification behaviour (sound and vibration) with this lines of code.

```
Notification arrivalNotification = mBuilder.build();
arrivalNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, arrivalNotification);
```

You could activate it again with:

```
int defaults = 0;
defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
mBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);
mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

I hope this help you! ;)

Comment: Adding to this, For generating vibration, instead of using `arrivalNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;` you can also use a pattern of your own.Something like `long pattern[]={0,2000,500,2000};`.And you can set vibration using `.setVibrate(pattern)`.It should work fine.